# Androdi Kotlin view is hidden when scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want my `RecyclerView`'s y to scroll according to R.id.ll_toolbar's y position. But now only when R.id.ll_toolbar position == 0 my R.id.item_parent is visible but if R.id.ll_toolbar position != 0 then R.id.item_parent is hidden (I set that in `listenForToolbarPositionChange()` methid). This is the problem of my post.

I need to add, this R.id.item_parent is in `Fragment`'s layout that is placed in R.id.fragment_container of parent (here is also R.id.ll_toolbar). Everything is shown at the code:

MainActivity.kt

```
private fun listenForToolbarPositionChange() {
    ll_toolbar.addOnLayoutChangeListener { v, left, top, right, bottom, oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom ->
        llHeaderY =  v.y
        item_parent.y = llHeaderY
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pl.jawegiel.exchangerates.ClickableMotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    motion:layoutDescription="@xml/main_activity_scene">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/exchange_rates"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/teal_700"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_header">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_inside_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_title"
                android:text="fragment"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="ABOUT"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</pl.jawegiel.exchangerates.ClickableMotionLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/item_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_subitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_date" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```